# App crashing suddenly on launch - iPhone enterprise version

Tags: iphone, crash, ios-enterprise

I have enterprise version installed on few of the devices. 
On one of the device app is crashing immediate after the launch button click every time.

It is working on other device without crash. Can any one help me on the issue that why it is crashing ?

**edit:
We seems it certificate expiration issue. But if certificate is expired then it also should not work when I install it in new device.

Comment: app crashes on some devices.. is it cydia device ?

Comment: No its normal iphone 6. with updated os.

Comment: @Esha check out my answer will surely help you

Comment: I’m suddenly facing the exact same issue. I’m not also able to reinstall the app

Comment: we’re having the same issue for multiple users. did you guys ever figure this out?

Comment: I had the same issue recently. all the devices were working fine and suddenly few of them started to crash on the same day. couldn't even debug it because it crashes the second I press the app icon. I'm still looking for a reason for it so if you've found out anything please let me know.

Comment: Did anyone found the solution for this, or maybe the reason. Same is happening with one of my app.

Comment: facing the same issue did anyone found a solution

Answer (score 1):

Here are few steps will help you to find / detect / resolve your issue :

> - If its live version which you are testing than check out crash logs.
> - To check crash logs open Xcode -> window -> Organiser -> Select your app -> Crashes -> Select current version. You will find the crash
>     open it in Xcode it will help you to find the line which generating
>     crash
> - If its not live app than try to debug app on same device using debug ad hoc provisioning
> - Another way is you can also use crashlytics tool into your app. It will give you detailed information of the crash along with the
>     possible code which encouraging the crash

Possible reasons for crash :

> - Architecture support. Might be crash issue generated only on base 64 devices than check out your app is base 64 supported or not
> - Use of Depreciated methods can also cause the crash
> - iOS Compatibility issue can also be a reason of crash
> - Most important reason is if your app trying to access privacy information without permission alert than also it will get crashed at
>     very beginning of app launch

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks @mayur but its not live version its enterprise distribution app. and Its not crashing for all device. Just for single device. BY debug it working perfectly on any other devices.

Comment: @Esha ohh seems like a complex issue +1 for it. I already said in answer you better use crashlytics tool to identify bug.

Comment: Yes Thanks. and will upvote the ans for the way to find it.

Answer (score 0):

We figured out this but posting bit late.

Few data systems and validation not matched in case of the Date Time system used. Date Time formats are different according to user and devices. Few systems have date formate as a month in the first 3 characters longer than the year(e.g. 1 Aug 2020). (from the same region devices, the date time format could be different). so **this validation is very critical and needs to consider** and all test cases. This was the issue we were facing as in the start we were opening the calendar and fetching the events accordingly.

Also displaying data on threads and managing threads are also more important in this kind of case. Memory leaks and appropriate GCD usage may also lead to this situation.

Thanks